# use angular link to validate Form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use `Angular` link to validate phone number. When user write the 12th number, then delete the number.

But it runs the first time 
       does not run the second time,
       and runs the third time.

```js
cardApp.directive('integer', function() {
 return {
  require : 'ngModel',
  controller : function($scope, $element) {
   
   
  },
  link : function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
   elm.bind("keyup",function(){
    scope.phoneNumber = 881;
    console.log("message");
   })
   scope.phoneNumber = 883;
   // ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
   //   scope.phoneNumber = 881;
   // });
   // ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
    
   //   scope.phoneNumber = 882;
   // });
  }
 };
});
```

Thanks a lot .

Comment: you could use `$validators` here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$validators

Comment: Thank you.I want to know $validators can change the value when it return false?